# heat flow finite difference

Tags: numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-differences

I'm trying to solve one dimension heat flow equation using finite difference and I feel like I'm making a huge mistake somewhere and I have no idea where.

I have a assumed a boundary condition and a set of initial values of temperatures at time = 0

I then use equation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLdMv.png) to obtain second partial derivative of heat equation by x from my initial values

According to heat equation [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZucFi.png) the first partial derivative of heat equation by time is equal to second partial derivative by x.

Shouldn't then multiplying the the first partial derivative by delta-time give me the new temperatures at time t plus delta?

It sounds so intuitive for me but when I plug all of this into excel, the values calculated are far from reasonable.

[Central finite difference for second derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLdMv.png)

Comment: Multiplying by delta-time gives you the change in temperatures. You must add this to the temperatures at the previous step. However, without actually seeing a minimal example it's hard to tell where the issue is stemming from.

Comment: It seems that was it

Comment: This is a 3D plot of solution where z-axis is the time

https://i.ibb.co/Zgd3JqT/solution.png

Comment: Please type the equations here in MathJax and do not reference pictures. It is very inconvenient to not see all on one page.